# How come the order of CSS includes doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, templates

```
<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In style1, let's say I declare color to be white:

```
.box{
    color:#fff;
}
```

In style2, I declare it to be black.

```
.box{
    color:#000;
}
```

How come style1 takes priority?

Comment: Because something else is going on. Show us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or you're wasting everyone's time, including your own.

Comment: It's supposed to be the last rule wins when it's the same weight. Check your browser's debug/dev tools network panel. What is the order the files are finished downloading?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772333/are-css-stylesheets-loaded-asynchronously

Comment: Never had a small answer converted to comment before :) It threw some javascript error... Fail whale SO

Comment: Just post a link to the site.

Comment: Agree with Matt above but in any case for CSS cascade, a good read is at http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-cascade/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both CSS contains the exact same css class, the last loaded CSS file will be looked upon as an extender - meaning you have to put `!important` after the last defined style in your css.

Sample

Style1

```
.box{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Style2

```
.box{
    color:#000 !important;
}
```

This way, Style2 will at all times overrule Style1.